# Error while clicking button

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am try to click on button but its throwing an error.

Selenium code is

```
WebElement sa = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div[7]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/a[1]/div/div/div[2]"));
         ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", sa);
```

Error i am getting is :

> Element is not clickable at point (215, 105). Other element would receive the click: `<svg style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1287" version="1.1" height="100"></svg>`

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to explicit wait the page to load. Or the page is loaded but the element is not visible for some reason. You can to scroll the page to where the element is.

(driver as IJavaScriptExecutor).ExecuteScript(string.Format("window.scrollTo(0, {0});",
elementToClick.Location.Y));

// Click the element
elementToClick.Click();

The example you can find here:
[Chrome - Element is not clickable at point #2766](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/2766)

Answer (score 0):

Actually provided exception would be throw when you use `.click()` of `WebElement` method instead of using `javascript` `click`, So are you sure this exception is throwing in this line when you are going to click using `JavascriptExexutor`??

Anyway You can try using `By.cssSelector()` to perform click on this `div` as below :-

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.question_text")).click();
```

**Edited** :- If you're still getting same exception you need to scroll first to reach that element using `JavascriptExexutor` then click as below :-

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.question_text"));

//Now scroll to reach that element 
((JavascriptExexutor)driver).exexuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", el);

//now click on this link 
el.click();
```

Comment: still same error Element is not clickable at point(460,11.39999)

Comment: Ok the you need to scroll first to reach that element before click. Try with edited answer and let me know..:)

Comment: You need to identify which element is clickable and pass that element to perform click...:)

Comment: If you want to click on `yes` button use this locator `By.cssSelector("div.centered.statement")` or `By.xpath(".//div[text() = 'Yes']")` and let me know..:)

Comment: Ok try once as `WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[text() = 'Yes']"));        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", el);` and let me know..:)

Comment: What do you mean same error??? I think you are using `.click()` of WebElement method somewhere in your code which is throwing this error because if you would use JavaScript `click()` this would never throw this error.. please debug your code and see where actually this error occurred...:)